# Non asmx?wsdl SOAP server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, cgi

I am looking for some advices and exmaples. Since now I havent seen trouble consuming SOAP services with PHP.
A third party has developed a service, they provided me a file with the WSDL and all the needed XSD schemas. But since their service URL has this look : https://webservice.com/xml_listen.cgi I am really struggling how to approach it.
I have tried the basic stuff that I have used until this moment about the previous services that I have consumed like:

```
    $client = new SoapClient(array(
   'location' => "https://webservice.com/xml_listen.cgi",
   'uri'      => "https://webservice.com/xml_listen.cgi",
   'trace'    => 1 ));
    $return = $client->__soapCall("SomeFuncion",array());
    var_dump($return);
```

I am hoping to find a way how to consume this kind of non WSDL services.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your question exactly ? And why you use "null" for the 1 argument? I initiate my soap like this : `new SoapClient(URLWEBSERVICE_SOAP, array([...]));`And I advices you to use try/catch for this (particulary if it's a third party has developed a service)

Comment: How to consume a non wsdl soap service ?

Comment: since they provided you wirt wsdl file try this `$client = new SoapClient($providedWSDLFilePath, array(
   'location' => "https://webservice.com/xml_listen.cgi",
   'trace'    => 1 ));
    $return = $client->__soapCall("SomeFuncion",array());
    var_dump($return);`